# Is it possible to pass arguments into a modal window? Need the modal to reference an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I'm trying to add a custom delete confirmation using a modal, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to pass an object into the modal so it can be referenced in the delete action.

**view.html.erb**

```
<% current_user_highlights.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag image.file_url(:small_thumb) } %>
  <span class="overlay btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target"#delete-highlight-confirmation-modal">DELETE</span>
<% end %>
```

**modal.html.erb**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete-highlight-confirmation-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" align="center">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Are you sure you want to delete this highlight?</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="delete-highlight-parent-image"> </div>
        <div id="delete-highlight-crop-image"></div>
        <br>
```

**This is where I'm stuck... Is there any way to "use" the image variable that is referenced in the view's block so it knows which image it should be deleting?**

```
        <%= link_to "Yes, delete it", image_path(image), method: :delete, data: { remote: true }, class: "overlay btn btn-sm btn-danger, id: "yes-delete-button"  %>

        <%= button_tag "No, keep it", class: "btn btn-lg btn-default", id: "no-keep-button", data: { dismiss: "modal" }%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help and insight you can offer!

---

### ***UPDATE:***

Here is something I've tried since this post. It seems I'm getting closer, but not quite there yet...

First, I set a `data-image` attribute within the view's button

```
<span class="overlay btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-highlight-confirmation-modal" data-image=<%= image_path(image) %>>DELETE</span>
```

Then, I apply that attribute to the 'href' attribute through javascript/jquery

```
let $deleteImageButton = $('#yes-delete-button');
$deleteImageButton.attr('href', $(this).data('image'));
```

This is returning an error:

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/images/97 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The good news, though, is that Image Id #97 does correspond with the image that's in the modal.

Any idea where I can go from here? Again, what I'm after is the destroy action within the images_controller and to pass in the correct image id.

---

### ***UPDATE 2:***

When it came to the Internal Server Error I was receiving, it had to do with some old ajax code hanging around from earlier attempts. Once I cleared that out, it's going through as expected.

```
$yesDeleteButton.off().on('click', function(event) {
  // event.preventDefault();
  $(this)
    .off('ajax:beforeSend')
    .on('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
      $body.addClass('loading');
    });
  $(this)
    .off('ajax:success')
    .on('ajax:success', function() {
      $body.removeClass('loading');
  });
```

I'm still not 100% sure how to get the initial delete link object to "pass" over to the modal, but I'm still trying things here and there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

May not be the cleanest way, but one solution was to first integrate a data-attribute within the initial link in the view that referenced the image, then use that data value to set the href attribute with jQuery. The main shift in my thinking was to completely separate the needed value from the modal entirely, and see it as nothing more than a Javascript/jQuery value that needed to be stored and later retrieved.

**view.html.erb**

```
<span class="overlay btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-highlight-confirmation-modal" data-image=<%= image_path(image) %>>DELETE</span>
```

**.js**

```
let selectedImagePath;
$highlightDeleteButtons.off().on('click', function(event) {
  // ...
  if ($(this).attr('data-imagepath') !== undefined) {
    $selectedImagePath = $(this).attr('data-imagepath');
  } else if ($(this).siblings('img')[0].dataset.imagepath !== undefined)  {
    $selectedImagePath = $(this).siblings('img')[0].dataset.imagepath;
  }
  // ...
});

let $deleteImageButton = $('#yes-delete-button');
$deleteImageButton.attr('href', $selectedImagePath);
```

When it came to the Internal Server Error I was receiving, it had to do with some old ajax code hanging around from earlier attempts. Once I cleared that out and used something along the lines of the below, it went through like a charm!

```
$yesDeleteButton.off().on('click', function(event) {
  // event.preventDefault();
  $(this)
    .off('ajax:beforeSend')
    .on('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
      $body.addClass('loading');
    });
  $(this)
    .off('ajax:success')
    .on('ajax:success', function() {
      $body.removeClass('loading');
  });
```